# SELECT * FROM WHERE Query isn't retrieving any results

Tags: mysql, select, mysqli, fetch

I'm using a `SELECT * FROM "" WHERE "" = ""` query and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with it. I'm trying to select an item based on its PO which is a completely unique identifier to one row in the table. Here's my process in doing so:

```
$jobnumber = $_GET['jref'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `po_10152796` WHERE `po` = " .$jobnumber;
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$rowitem = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
    $jobname = $rowitem['Job Name'];
    $phone = $rowitem['phone'];
```

Things i know are correct:

- The "jobnumber" is retrieved correctly and matches up with an element in the table
- The table is named "po_10152796" and there is a column named "po"

[image]

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). and a query which returns no results is **NOT** an error. it's a perfectly valid result set that happens to be empty.

Comment: It's a logic error, which is what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: What does `echo $query;` show you?  Maybe your query is not formatted properly or you're not quoting a string value.  P.S. Please use prepared statements.

Comment: That shows "SELECT * FROM `po_10152796` WHERE `po` = 1 " for example

Comment: nothing wrong with the sql logic. you're just passing in an id which doesn't exist in the db.

Comment: Added a picture showing that such a line does exist.

Comment: So... what exactly is the problem you're having then?  What do `var_dump($results);` and `var_dump($rowitem);` show?

Comment: This might be a long shot, but what if `$conn` by any chance is not the correct connection variable?

Comment: @RocketHazmat I get NULL

Comment: @Nikola Thanks for the thought but it is correct =3

Comment: @NathanGeist: Both are `NULL`?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Correct, both are NULL.

Comment: I'm going to try and redo the entire thing using prepared statements and see if I can fix the error during the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot to post this, redid the code with prepared statements and it works, not sure what exactly I changed but here it is anyhow:

```
    $jobnumber = $_GET['jref'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare( "SELECT `Job Name`, `Address`, `phone`, `description`, `materials` FROM po_10152796 WHERE po = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $jobnumber);
if($stmt->execute()){
    $stmt->bind_result($jobname, $address, $phone, $description, $materials);
    $stmt->fetch();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

try this line for the query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `po_10152796` WHERE `po` = '" .$jobnumber. "' ";
```

Comment: that's not going to help. if it was a string error, the query would have failed and been caught by the `or die()`